# Always getting NULL when running a query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

So I'm trying to get an updated list of likes when the user refreshes the page. The issue is I get

> Notice: Undefined variable: post in /Users/matt/Desktop/Likers/home/index.php on line 54

Line 54 is `var_dump($post['id']);`. I end up getting `NULL` on that, which should be happening. Now here's how I'm querying

```
$qry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_user IN (SELECT follow_to FROM followers WHERE follow_from = :user)");
$qry->bindValue(':user', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$qry->execute();

    $posts = array();
    while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $posts[] =  array(
        'post_user' => $row['post_user'],
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'post_date' => $row['post_date'],
        'post_likes' => $row['post_likes'],
        'post_content' => $row['post_content']
    );
    }   

var_dump($post['id']);
```

So I'm basically not getting `id`. While in my database I have `id`

Comment: `$posts[0]['id'] or $posts[1]['id'] or $posts[2]['id'].... so on`

Comment: @FerozAkbar You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're defining an array `$posts[]` and then dumping `$post['id']`. First, `$post` should be `$posts`, and secondly, you're adding to the array so it'll have an index `$posts[0]['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

You will get array of records like

```
$posts = array('0' => array('id' => 1), '1' => array('id' => 2));
```

So you need to find id value using it's index value or using foreach loop.

```
foreach($posts as $post){
   var_dump($post['id']);
}
```